# Аксессор для доступа к массиву C#.

Tags: c#, access, массивы, .net, get

К обычным полям класса методы set и get, пишутся, как я понял примерно так:

```
string raion; 
        public string Raion
        {
            get
            {
                return raion;
            }
            set
            {
                raion = value;
            }
        }
А как принято делать это для массивов?
```

Answer (score 5):

```
public float this[int index]
{
    get
    {
        return temps[index];
    }

    set
    {
        temps[index] = value;
    }
}
```

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/2549tw02.aspx)